# Why does Joseph tell Elle she isn't a replicant?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-black-lotus

Joseph manages to save Elle from her own folly after she

> kills Senator Bannister, who would have done the same to her.

She is clearly confused and worried she's a replicant. Joseph administers a Voight-Kampff test after failing to find a serial number in her eye. After she answers the question about being in love, he tells her she's not a replicant. The problem is the show has already shown her with the cat-like reflection in her eyes, and her actions have been superhuman in taking out a gang in a prior episode. After Joseph decrypts the video recorder and sees what Elle saw, it had to be clear to him she was a replicant.

Was Joseph merely fooled by Elle, or was he lying to her?

Comment: I'd say he was telling her what he thought she was hoping to hear, but that's just me.

Comment: Joseph appears to be lying and telling her precisely what she wants to hear, that she's not a replicant, presumably in the hope that she can be persuaded to stop killing people who've pissed her off. For the record, the number of questions asked is well below the number needed to detect even an early model replicant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Joseph was indeed lying. I base that on later episodes

> Joseph is in on the plot of Niander Wallace Jr. using Elle to kill off his father and compatriots. At the stage of the story, Joseph needs to keep Elle in the dark about who she is, or she might remember too much.

Comment: Plus the fact that his Voight Kampff test was totally nonsense. He only asked her two or three questions